# Foreach inside a Switch case for language selection with session

Tags: php, session, foreach

Creating language selection with session value set using form select option. Here is the code what i am trying to do with but i see only blank page.

```
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM languages";
$langs = mysqli_query($sql);

$locale = strtolower($_POST['locale']);

if (!empty($locale)) { 
    switch ($locale) {
        foreach($langs as $lang) {
         case $lang['code']:
            $_SESSION['code'] = $lang['code'];
        }
        default:
            $_SESSION['code'] = 'en';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: switch/case doesn't work like that; you can't define the cases dynamically.... you shuld be getting a syntax error like `unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT)` to tell you this

Comment: it hast to be blank because you not outputing anything

Comment: You should just be using an if in this situation

Comment: You have a _syntax error_. Enable the `display_errors`, setup `error_reporing` and see the error message. http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Comment: why do you need to use switch ... case?

Comment: Any ways to use switch case dynamically ?

Comment: @user1844933 not particularly but i am looking better way to change language using select option

Comment: @mkrahamath No! You must identify the cases explicitly in your code.... use the right control structures for the situation; don't try to shoehorn incorrect control structures into the wrong situation

Comment: What's wrong with adding a WHERE clause on the locale to your query, and a simple if test depending on whether there's a result or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest part of the switch syntax into a foreach like that, doing so will cause a fatal error.

That said, you don't need a switch.

This should have the desired effect:

```
if (!empty($locale)) { 
    $_SESSION['code'] = 'en';
    foreach($langs as $lang) {
        if($lang['code'] == $locale){
            $_SESSION['code'] = $lang['code'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest the switch cases inside a foreach loop, I assume the white page is actually a PHP fatal error.

Fortunately, you don't need a complex switch statement here, this should do the job:

```
$langs = ["en", "fr", "fa", "es"];
$locale = strtolower($_POST['locale']);

if (in_array($locale, $langs, true)) {
    $_SESSION['code'] = $locale;
} else {
    $_SESSION['code'] = 'en';
}
```

**Note:** This answer has been given before OP's code changes.

Answer (score 0):

It makes much more sense to find the provided locale in database instead of querying all locales and then looping over them to find a match. You spare yourself uneccessary loop this way:

```
session_start();
$locale = strtolower(isset($_POST['locale']) ? $_POST['locale'] : '');

// don't forget to sanitize 'locale'
$sql = "SELECT code FROM languages WHERE code LIKE '%$locale%' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$_SESSION['code'] = $locale ? $result[0]['code'] : 'en';
```